# Fro the map view zoom out in UI testing not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

For the UI Test case I need to "zoom out" in the map view. When using pinch zoom out code it only moves map to the left.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.maps.element.pinch(withScale: 0.9, velocity: -0.5)
```

Dose someone knows how to achieve "zoom out" functionality in the UI Testing?

I want to notice that "zoom in" works fine.

Comment: I just tried on a simple project with a fullscreen map and it worked fine on both Xcode 8 and 9 and iSO 10 and 11. Do you have a sample project where you can reproduce it?

Comment: @TitouandeBailleul Unfortunately it is not working in [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hmxrLGwM6zWlpsbDVuQ05OV2c/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Don't have time to look at it at the moment but here's a project where it works and it doesn't look so much different from yours: https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/Map

Comment: Thanks for the project I will look what is different.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to make it work? I am stuck with the same problem: only zooming in is working as expected.

Comment: @adauguet I did not found way how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one finger of the simulated pinch gesture is falling on the status bar, so only the other finger is registered.

You can solve the problem in your example project by adding the following to `ViewController.swift`:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

When zooming *out*, the UI test system seems to simulate a pinch from the very top left and bottom right of the view, constrained to the edges of the screen. This doesn't seem to take the status bar into account, and so the top-left touch falls on the status bar and is ignored, and only the bottom-right touch is registered by the view, causing the pinch to become instead a drag up and left. This isn't just with maps, it seems to be an issue with all scroll views.

If you *do* want to display the status bar on top of the view, you may need to figure out another way to constrain your pinch to not fall on the status bar. In my case, I was fine simply removing the status bar.

Comment: I've been struggling over zoom out and tried this. Instead of nothing, I get a pan gesture. At a guess, ONE of the pinch points is registering while the other one fails and so the it pans instead. Most likely the one where the status bar was is the one now functional. This does not seem to be desired behavior. Did you file a radar on it?

Comment: I never did file a radar for it, no. Seems like a good idea if you want to file one.

Comment: I did, but your answer as a long time ago so I was curious if you had and gotten a response.